# CGMiner error: SEM: Icarus USB timeout waiting for

Tags: bitcoin, mining

I set up CGMiner 3.8.1 (even the one before this version) on MACOS X 10.8.5
I have 11 Block Erupters but the CGMiner just see 10 and keep giving this error: SEM: Icarus USB timeout waiting for (blah blah).
I already changed usb hub, plugged the usbs direct into the computer but nothing seems to fix it.
BFGMiner sees and recognize all of them, I just really don't like it.

Do you guys know what I can do to fix CGMiner?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

cgminer uses SysV semaphores and makes use of the UNDO mechanism. Most OSs have low settings of this value (kern.sysv.semume), usually 10 or less. Use 'sysctl' to adjust that value upwards. You may need to do this via /etc/sysctl.conf and reboot.

Comment: Looking at `sysctl -a | grep semume` it is indeed set to 10.  Trying to write a new value, `sudo sysctl -w kern.sysv.semume=15` throws "sysctl: kern.sysv.semume: Invalid argument" and `/etc/sysctl.conf` does not exist on 10.9.  Any suggestions?